# Combine Excel Functions: Match & Offset

Tags: excel, match, offset

I am trying to combine a couple of excel functions. The main functions are Match and Offset.
I am trying to find a value (date) in AQ12 within another sheet in row  9). In this case it would return cell address G9. (Not $G$9 as this won't work in the offset function). From there I want to perform a SUMIF on G13:G100.

What I have at the moment is:

`=ADDRESS(CELL("row",INDEX('Employee Resource'!G9:XFD9,,MATCH(AQ12,'Employee Resource'!G9:XFD9,0))),CELL("col",INDEX('Employee Resource'!G9:XFD9,,MATCH(AQ12,'Employee Resource'!G9:XFD9,0))),4)`

which returns G9, which is fine as I know the sheet name. Let's call it "Employee Resource" for argument sake.  (Plus it is in the function above).

I need to use that "G9" and the sheetname "Employee Resource" to produce something like:

`=COUNTIFS('Employee Resource'!G10:G100,$B$4)`

So I guess it would be something like
`=COUNTIFS("'Employee Resource'!"&"G10"&":"&"G100",$B$4)`

Where G10 and G100 are offsets of the original function
G10 = OFFSET(...,0,1)
G100 = OFFSET(...,0,91)
But these return an error. (Not a #N/A or ERROR, but doesn't let me enter it.

Does anyone know why? I have tried other mixtures such as...

I believe I can use Offset to create a range
G10:G100 = OFFSET(...,0,1,0,90)

`=OFFSET('Employee Resource'!G9,0,1)` returns a date value not address G10 which is what I would expect.

`=CELL("address",OFFSET('Employee Resource'!$G$9,91,0))` returns "'[New Production Schedule II.xlsm]Employee Resource'!$G$100" so includes the workbook name & sheet & cell but as an absolute reference.

`=CELL("address",OFFSET('Employee Resource'!$G$9,11,0))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET('Employee Resource'!$G$9,91,0))` returns
'[New Production Schedule II.xlsm]Employee Resource'!$G$20:'[New Production Schedule II.xlsm]Employee Resource'!$G$100
When I add the SUM function it returns #VALUE!. If I do it via text without the function result it works fine albeit removing the workbook name. I think the issue is I need to use the result in the SUM function in this instance.

Using the function INDIRECT should allow me to use the result but `=SUM(INDIRECT(CELL("address",OFFSET('Employee Resource'!$G$9,11,0))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET('Employee Resource'!$G$9,91,0))))` returns #REF!

Answer (score 0):

It can be simpler:

```
MATCH(AQ12,'Employee Resource'!G9:XFD9,0)
```

will return a column offset from Col F where the date of interest is found.

So the Countif then becomes:

```
 COUNTIF(OFFSET('Employee Resource'!F10:F100,0,
    MATCH(AQ12,'Employee Resource'!G9:XFD9,0)),B4)
```

...although it's not clear if you want a `COUNTIF()` (you also talk about SUMIF)